# Keeping only the latest revision of documents in a list

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a list like this:

Document #1 PB
Document #1 PC
Document #2 PB
Document #2 PC
Document #2 PD
Document #3 PA
Document #4 PB
Document #4 PC
...

For like 700 rows. The revisions (PA, PB, PC, etc.) and the document number are not in the same column.

How could I filter out/delete any row that isn't the latest revision of a document that comes up more than once in the list?

The latest is determined this way: PC>PB, PD>PC

Also, for information, the documents numbers are composed of letters and numbers

I don't mind the solution being in VBA or only in Excel formulas.

Comment: How do you know which is the last?

Comment: Yes sry I should have clearified this but the latest revision is the highest letter if that makes sense. For example PC is the newer revision over PB so PC > PB.

Comment: Sort descending on the P@ column and then use remove duplicates on the data tab.

Comment: Which ones would you like to be gone in the Sample Data ? 1st, 3rd, 4th, second last ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a VBA solution this should work too. I'm assuming you have your data laid out like: Document Name in the column to the left of the revision string.

This works by adding document names to a dictionary, when the same document appears more than once, the revision numbers are compared by converting to a number and updating the dictionary when a new value has been discovered that is larger.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ConvertRangeToDict()
    Dim mySearchRange       As Excel.Range
    Dim LatestRevisions     As Object
    Dim mySheet             As Excel.Worksheet

    Set mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Update your sheet reference
    Set mySearchRange = mySheet.Range("A1:A1000") 'Only pass in Document name range, one column only
    Set LatestRevisions = GetLatestRevisions(mySearchRange)

    With LatestRevisions
        mySheet.Range("D1").Resize(.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(.keys)
        mySheet.Range("E1").Resize(.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(.items)
    End With

End Sub

Public Function GetLatestRevisions(SearchRng As Range) As Object
    Dim dict            As Object
    Dim Cell            As Excel.Range
    Dim RevisionInDict  As Long
    Dim Revision        As Long

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    If SearchRng.Columns.Count > 1 Then Exit Function

    For Each Cell In SearchRng
        If Not dict.Exists(Cell.Value) Then
            dict.Add Cell.Value, Cell.Offset(0, 1) 'I'm assuming the revisions are stored in the cell to the right
        Else
            RevisionInDict = ConvertTextToNumeric(dict(Cell.Value))
            Revision = ConvertTextToNumeric(Cell.Offset(0, 1))
            If Revision > RevisionInDict Then dict(Cell.Value) = Cell.Offset(0, 1)
        End If
    Next

    Set GetLatestRevisions = dict
End Function

Public Function ConvertTextToNumeric(CellValue As String) As Long
    Dim i            As Long
    Dim NumberString As String

    For i = 1 To Len(CellValue)
        NumberString = NumberString & CStr(Asc(Mid$(UCase(CellValue), i, 1)))
    Next

    ConvertTextToNumeric = CLng(NumberString)
End Function
```

Comment: Wow this looks great I haven't tried it yet ut will certainly do and give you comments when i have!

Comment: Hello, I manage to make your code work with my file its great and works really fast ! Would it be possible to copy the entire row (up to like column V) of the latest document row?

Comment: Hi, glad the approach is helping some. Not sure I understand the ask. However, if you are looking to copy the whole row, you could store a range as the dictionary value instead of the revision text.

Answer (score 1):

As Far as I understood, this is one way of doing it. A bit complex, but I enjoyed solving it though.

**Steps:**

- Sort your data from a to z using 2nd column with PA, PB etc
- Copy paste All the Document Numbers in a New Column and Run the Remove Duplicates on them.
- In the Next column Apply a CountIf `=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$9,F2)` as per screenshot.
- Now create a Helper column using function `=COUNTIF($B$2:$B2,B2) & B2`
- Lastly apply Vlookup `=VLOOKUP(G2&F2,$A$2:$C$9,3,FALSE)`

See the Screenshot for References of where to apply.

[image]

You will have a List of Unique Documents with Latest version in Last.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will use this to have a reference to what the actual latest list of documents is when i try do use a macro later.